# Monitoring progress in Python parallel processes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, global-variables, counter, python-multiprocessing

The following code returns the error:

```
local variable 'count' referenced before assignment.
```

Below are the two functions:

```
def run():
    ...
    global count
    count = 0
    with closing(Pool(processes=4)) as pool:
    pool.map(run_in_parallel, listOfIds)
    pool.terminate()
    ...

def run_in_parallel(id):
    count += 1
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print('Processed %d %s' % (count, time.strftime('%x %X')))
    # Do main work in parallel
```

The error pops up only because of the modifying statement. i.e.

```
count +=1
```

I have read in several places that it is not a good practice to modify global variables in worker processes. But since the listOfIds is a huge list, I need some way of monitoring progress and printing to terminal once in a while. How is this to be done?

I have read other posts on StackOverflow and other places and none of the other questions address the exact same problem described above.

Comment: Using and accessing global variables will not work like you expect it in a multiprocessing program

Comment: Here's a good example/explanation of how to implement a shared counter: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs most likely because you were not making the global variable `count` available via `global count`, like you did in your `run()` function.

Anyways, this will not work like you want it to work. Every spawned process will have it's own global `count` variable, which it will increment and which will always be `0` at creation time.

If you want to count it like that, you should use the example that Tom Dalton was linking for you:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def func(val):
    for i in range(50):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        val.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Value('i', 0)
    procs = [Process(target=func, args=(v,)) for i in range(10)]

    for p in procs: p.start()
    for p in procs: p.join()

    print v.value
```